# Access data from SharePoint-hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to get a grip of apps for SharePoint. What I have not yet clearly understood is whether it would basically be **possible to access SharePoint-objects, e.g. a public outlook calendar, from a SharePoint-hosted app via the JSOM?**

Would I need a provider hosted app and access via the REST-Api & CSOM instead?

I'd be thankful for a short comment.

Comment: [Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx) [Link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163794.aspx)

Comment: These are nice links which I've encountered before, it's just too much information. It reads like you can do everything, with JSOM as well, and "Access objects in the host web" sounds like what I am looking for. But from the examples given there, I am asking myself... whaaat? I'd expect there to be a class "Outlook" or something.

Comment: It's not a outlook calendar, it's just a calendar... but it's not a calendar it's just a list.. you can do same operation of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a regular calendar in the host web, you can access its data via CSOM or REST Api.

Have a look at the following URLs go get a better idea.

CSOM : [BasicOps SPListItemTasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks)

REST: [Rest operations](http://blog.ctp.com/2014/04/28/performing-rest-operations-on-host-webs-from-sharepoint-hosted-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SharePoint Hosted Add In (new name for hosted app) to achieve what you are talking about. SharePoint hosted and Provider hosted are no different with regards to whether you can or cannot access data in the host web, instead, they are different in the technologies you are able to use and the infrastructure required.